¿Como solucionar este error al compilar en valac?
Estoy teniendo un error al compilar mi código hecho en Vala, específicamente usando Valac para compilarlo. Cuando ejecuto el comando  valac --pkg=gee-0.8,glib-2.0 RunPythonScript.vala ya que uso la librería GLib y Gee ocurre este error:  Package `gee-0.8,glib-2.0' not found in specified Vala API directories or GObject-Introspection GIR directories
He probado de diferentes maneras, pero no encuentro una solución, ¿alguien puede ayudarme?
